# Apple Pay Peripheral

Tags: lightning, apple-pay

I use an iPhone 5S, as I was unable to wait until the 6 came out (my screen was destroyed on my old phone). Is there any peripheral which allows me to use Apple Pay on my phone?

Comment: I don't think I've heard of any. Something like a Apple Pay case with NFC should come out soon by third-party company.

Comment: I picked up an iPhone 6 last week and was suprised I could not yet use ApplePay.  The Visa/MC/Amex logo on the card is not enough to make it work, the list of participating banks is actually still fairly short. See http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6288

Answer (score 1):

No. You can't put an NFC chip into a 5s, even with external hardware.

Comment: Explain, why not ? provide source !